# Is there a way to print Proc Univariate output for Fitted distribution?

Tags: sas, distribution

I have a dataset of observed data and I want to test if they are ~ LogNormal (μ;σ)

I have used the following:

```
Proc Univariate data=myData;
var Var1;
histogram / LogNormal;
run;
```

I have, as an output, different tables and I would like to store in a Table the results of the "Parameters for Lognormal Distribution".

### Parameters for Lognormal Distribution (Example)

| Parameter | Symbol | Estimate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Threshold | Theta | 0 |
| Scale | Zeta | 9.09 |
| Shape | Sigma | 1.04 |

However, it seems to me that I can only store basics statistics (e.g. normality test, skewness test)

Anyone may help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable ODS Trace and you can find the table that stores this information, then output it with `ods output`. For example:

```
ods trace on;
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars;
    var horsepower;
    histogram / lognormal;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Check the log and you'll see:

```
Output Added:
-------------
Name:       ParameterEstimates
Label:      Parameter Estimates
Template:   base.univariate.FitParms
Path:       Univariate.Horsepower.Histogram.Lognormal.ParameterEstimates
-------------
```

Use `ods output` to grab the parameter estimates and save them to a table:

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars;
    var horsepower;
    histogram / lognormal;
    ods output ParameterEstimates;
run;
```

```
VarName     Histogram   Distribution    Parameter   Symbol  Estimate
Horsepower  1           Lognormal       Threshold   Theta   0
Horsepower  1           Lognormal       Scale       Zeta    5.321345
Horsepower  1           Lognormal       Shape       Sigma   0.328634
Horsepower  1           Lognormal       Mean                216.0145
Horsepower  1           Lognormal       Std Dev             72.95021
```